# Nginx proxy pass to dockerized gunicorn server

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

I try to deploy an app with the following architecture:

- the backend is based on a dockerized Django Rest Framework with gunicorn listening on 127.0.0.1:8000
- the frontend is based on VueJS (not dockerized) and make calls to my backend API routes
- NginX is used to serve frontend pages and to proxy API requests to gunicorn

Here is an excerpt of my backend docker-compose file:

```yaml
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/server/Dockerfile
    image: myserverimage
    command: 'gunicorn --bind=127.0.0.1:8000 --workers=3 my_backend.wsgi:application'
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

`docker-compose up` tells me everything looks fine for this part (server started and gunicorn is listening on `127.0.0.1:8000`)

And here is the server block from nginx config:

```
upstream backend {
                server 127.0.0.1:8000;
        }

server {
                listen 443 default_server ssl;
                server_name  mydomain.com;
                ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

                access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.access.log;

                location / {
                        root   /path/to/vue/project/dist;
                        index  index.html;
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                }

                location /backend/ {
                        proxy_pass http://backend/;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                }

  }
```

I can access to my frontend pages at mydomain.com but requests to `mydomain.com/backend` return `502 bad gateway` error.

If I change `127.0.0.1:8000` to `backend-container-ip:8000` in both nginx upstream declaration and gunicorn command, it works.

So my question is: is there a way to configure such architecture whitout having to know the container ip (I don't want to hardcode it, especially in the docker-compose declaration) ?
Should I create an additional container with nginx, even if my frontend is not based on the docker-compose definition ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you sending the request inside the same `nginx` container instead of sending it to the `gunicorn` container.

Instead of:

```
proxy_pass http://backend/;
```

you should refer to another container

```
proxy_pass http://server:8000;
```

Where `server` would be the DNS of the other container which would be running e.g. on `172.17.0.2` and might be substituted by Docker compose.

Comment: actually, nginx is not running within a container. I only use docker for the backend application. But it I get your point, you mean that I should specify the IP of the docker container (`172.17.0.2`) in the nginx conf and the docker-compose gunicorn command as well ? Don't you think this is a problem (IPs could change from one install to an other) ?

Comment: Yes, that would be a problem. Docker compose makes container discover-able via the container name, see e.g. https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: Thx for your feedback. Yes, they can be discoverable by the service name but only within the default network created by docker-compose, right ? In my case, nginx is installed on host and is not part of this docker-compose network.

Comment: Yes, you would need more advance service discovery in order to translate the address outside of Docker compose. If you are running just single container then use can use `network: host` which would bind gunicorn port `8000` on the host (unless you're using the port for some other service). Such setup is not recommended for larger number of containers, networking is not isolated. But you will be able to access `127.0.0.1:8000` from nginx.

Comment: I investigated the problem a bit further and I don't get why nginx can't proxy_pass the request to 127.0.0.1:8000 this way when I can access my database container at 127.0.0.1:5432. Ports are actually exposed in both cases. This should not work either, right ?

Comment: Is the container networking in `host` mode? Are you able from to run `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000` from local machine (outside Docker)?

Comment: I don't think it does because I'm relying of the default network creation. But I do expose the port 8000. Indeed, I get an error if I try to `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000` from the host. Yet, I can `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d my_db db_user` while having the database running as a container connected to the same docker default network which gets me confused.

Comment: It should be apparent from `docker inspect {container ID}` in `.NetworkSettings.Ports`. If you have `"8000/tcp": null` mapped to `null`, it isn't exposed.

Comment: Checked this settings and "8000/tcp" is mapped to `[{"HostIp":"127.0.0.1", "HostPort":"8000"}]`. Yet, I looked at another settings: `Config.ExposedPorts` and I have `"8000/tcp": {}`, but I don't know if this is relevant.

Comment: That seems to be ok. If you ran `netstat -lpn | grep 8000` you should see `docker-proxy` process. When you run ` docker inspect CONTAINER_ID -f '{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks}}'` you should see name of the network, e.g. `bridge`. And bellow you'll find an `IPAddress` field, e.g. `172.17.0.2`. You can try to access directly that IP. `curl -v http://172.17.0.2:8000`. If this works and direct access from host doesn't you might have problem with NAT.

Comment: If I change the gunicorn server to be bound to the appropriate `IPAddress` and try `curl -v http://10.11.0.7:8000` (which is my actual container IP), I do get a response indeed. What could be wrong with the NAT ? Also, I now have `"8000/tcp"` settings mapped to `[{"HostIp":"0.0.0.0", "HostPort":"8000"}]` but I don't know why, maybe some sort of cache on docker side ?

Comment: By default docker injects rules into `iptables`. Check `iptables -S | grep DOCKER` you should see there e.g. `DOCKER`, `DOCKER-USER`, `DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1`, `DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2` chains. There should be a rule like this: `-A DOCKER -d 10.11.0.7/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT` and in `iptables -S -t nat`: something like this: `-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.11.0.7:8000`

Comment: I do have these rules, but I get `br-4a33d1b74e59` instead of `docker0`. Like `-A DOCKER -d 10.11.0.7/32 ! -i br-4a33d1b74e59 -o br-4a33d1b74e59 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT` but on top of these, I have `-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER -A FORWARD -o br-4a33d1b74e59 -j DOCKER`

Comment: Yes, that's ok, but not necessarily correct. There's also `docker-proxy` process that might work as NAT. You have there most likely some configuration issue. But it's hard to tell from the information available.

Comment: OK, thx so much for your help anyway. I was reading about docker networking and I wonder if my issues could come from the fact that I use the default bridge network and not a user defined one… Also, do you know where I could get some further help (docker dedicated forum or so) about this kind of config issue ?

Comment: Default bridge is not a problem. Stackoverflow is ok, you just have to formulate question and provide sufficient details. If you have a running docker container where `docker ps` shows port mapping `0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp` and you are unable to access the endpoint via `curl -v http://0.0.0.0:8000` from the host, it might be a good question to start with.

Comment: I asked a new question with those details (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66139005/issue-connecting-to-docker-container-with-port-exposed-from-host). I found similar threads, but most of the solutions advise changing `--bind=127.0.0.1:8000` to `--bind=0.0.0.0:8000`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late to answer this, but I believe I can explain the problem. You have gunicorn listening on `127.0.0.1` - the localhost or **loopback IP**.

Just like a development build served on  localhost isn't accessible outside your machine, gunicorn bound to localhost is not accessible from outside the container. To solve this, bind to `0.0.0.0` instead.